# Basic way to send data to and from a js server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, client-server

I need to send small amounts of data (just 1 variable) back and forth between a html client page and a JS server. what would be the best way of going about this? (basically, what's a script I can add to my client to send and receive data from the server? the client is just HTML and CSS.)

Specifically, what I would like to be able to do is this:

send a variable to the server,

have the server do some things with that variable,

and send a different variable back.

(What the server is doing with the variable isn't relevant to the question.)

server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var listen = app.listen(process.env.PORT);
var io = require('socket.io')(listen);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/chat.html', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.info(`Client connected [id=${socket.id}]`);
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.info(`Client gone [id=${socket.id}]`);
  });
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('private message', ({ sender, recipient, message }) => {
     io.to([recipient]).emit("dm", {description: message, sender: sender });
  socket.on('passwordTest', function(test){
    console.log(test);
    io.emit('passwordCorrect')
  });

})
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('New Message');
  });
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg, xname){
    io.emit('chat message', msg, {senderid: xname });
    console.log('sender: ' + xname + ', message: ' + msg);
  });
});
```

Any example code you could provide would be great!

<3

Comment: Your question is too broad, but maybe looking into `fetch` is a good place to start. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: @jmargolisvt I added some more specifics to my question. Hopefully that makes it clearer!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to send the chatroom name and senders name along with the message. To do that you have to use javascript  in client side. Use an array to store the data once the  user connects and remove the details from array once user disconnects. This is required since multiple users may be using your chat app at once.

If you want further clarification please let me know with specific details, because I am kind of working on similar project